# Firebase Auth JWT IDToken: is server side verification always needed?

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, jwt

I'm using Firebase Auth for user sessions.
ID Token is stored client side, and sent on every request to my GAE back end.

It seems costly, so I want to avoid it if I can.
I suppose I don't need to verify it for public-facing GET (idempotent) endpoints, but for access-restricted requests and POST requests, do I always need to verify the token with each request, or is there a safe optimization like caching the verified ID tokens serverside?

Comment: It shouldn't be expensive as the public key is cached most of the time. You don't need to make network requests each time to retrieve it. You do have to verify it. The verification processing should be pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

Example :

```
/get/account/user1
```

When redirect in it, send it and verify it.
But ! if you're going on `/home`, if you don't need an authentification, it's not necessary to send it. 

Even more, I'll recommand to not send it when not needed.

If you've got a router, you should use some kind of `Array` with all routes which required your TOKEN ID and check the redirection :).